# What's a synonym for the "top cover" provided by one's manager?

Tags: manager, team, politics

There's a military slang term, "providing *[top cover](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/top%20cover)*":

> combat airplanes flying at high altitude to protect from air attack a military force especially of other airplanes flying at a lower altitude

That's used as a metaphor in the workplace: one of the things your manager does is provide "top cover" -- i.e. protect you from (interference by) other managers, including other managers from other departments, and higher-level managers.

It's a handy metaphor: useful and short.

But I'm worried that it isn't a well-known idiom (especially in other countries).

Is there some better-known business jargon, or plain English, that you'd use instead -- in a phrase like, "Our manager is helpful, even when we don't see him much he provides "top cover""?

Comment: Perhaps you should ask this on [english.se] instead.

Comment: Perhaps. Given it's so workplace-specific I thought I might get a better answer here.

Comment: @ChrisW while the context is workplace-specific, the question is not. The question can essentially boil down to: "What's a good synonym for X word", which means  English Language & Usage would probably be the better place to ask this.

Comment: Well OK, feel free to close it then.

Comment: This question (asking for a idiom/synonym/phrase) belongs to English Language & Usage as @SanderSkovgaardHansen already mentioned..

Comment: “Air cover” is a commonly used phrase in business for this, though I have never heard “top cover.”

Comment: **But I'm worried that it isn't a well-known idiom** - Why does this worry you? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Region specific I imagine, but the American Football phrase "blocking and tackling" is one I hear in the US and, less often, "running interference".

Answer (score 8):

Well there is nothing wrong with "provides top cover" or just "provides cover", but also:

"...has our backs..."
"...runs interference..."
"...protects his team..."

To name a few others.

Comment: "Well there is nothing wrong with provides top cover" So you think it's well-known? I'm inclined to; but I'm working in France and don't want to over-stretch people's knowledge of English. I know all "formal" French for example as it's taught in French primary school, but not necessarily "current" French, and I expect French people's English is similar. Thanks for those other suggestions, they don't have quite the same imagery but I think they're more well-known (or easier to find in an online dictionary).

Comment: I've heard all of these among native speakers in the US.  But these are generally idioms and may not translate well to non-native speakers or other cultures.  I can't even say myself whether these might be meaningful to listeners in the UK or AU.  As far as France?  I have no idea.  Sorry...

Comment: I'm Canadian, I think all three are well-known, though I guess the second is from American Football, and only the third is semi-literal instead of metaphorical.

Comment: @ChrisW while it may not be very well known, as a non-native speaker who heard the word for the first time I immediately understood what it meant. The word is rather self explanatory.

Answer (score 3):

Part of a managers role is to be a buffer and primary point of contact between his/her team and the rest of the World.

Answer (score 1):

Many military expressions don't translate well to civilian or corporate life.

SNAFU and FUBAR are two of the expressions, "got your six" is another one, but most other terms don't get into the common vernacular unless they trickle into the entertainment media.

Basically, if you've seen it on TV, it's a safe bet that it will be recognized.

Other than that, "got your back", "Looks out for his team", "won't throw you under the bus", "Keeps it within the team" all gets the message accross

Answer (score 1):

I think the term "gatekeeper" would be a good substitute here.